# A 'weird' topology: Hausdorff, quotients.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be obtained by taking two disjoint copies of the interval $[0,2]$ (with the Euclidean topology) and gluing each $t$ in the first copy with the corresponding $t$ in the second copy, for all $t \in [0,2]$ different from the middle point. Explicitely, one may take the space 
$$ Y=[0,2]\times \{0\} \cup [0,2] \times \{1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$$
with the topology induced from the Euclidean topology, and $X$ is the space obtained from $Y$ by gluing $(t,0)$ to $(t,1)$ for all $t\in [0,2], t\neq 1$. We endow $X$ with the quotient topology.

1. Is $X$ Hausdorff?
2. Show that $X$ can also be obtained as a quotient of the circle $S^1$.

I find this a very weird topology and hard to understand it. Also, I don't know how to proof some space is Hausdorff, I can't give a perfect proof of it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: This is a translated piece of what is often called the "line with doubled origin".  Do you think it is Hausdorff?  What open set separates the two distinct 1's?

Comment: For 2), think about identifying the endpoints first to get a quotient map from the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, the space $X$ is like an interval $[0, 2]$ but at $1$ there is a small infinitesimal "bump", and if you zoom in you'll see two pieces. Thus it's called the "line with two origins".

$X$ is not Hausdorff. Take image of the points $1 \times \{0\}$ and $1 \times \{1\}$ by the quotient map $q : Y \to X$. Any neighborhood of the two points will intersect.

$X$ can be obtained from the quotient of $S^1$ as follows. Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S^1 \subset \Bbb R^2$ as follows: $(x, y) \sim (x, -y)$ for all points on $S^1$ such that $(x, y) \neq (0, 1)$. Essentially, all we did was to identify the two points of the intervals in $Y$ beforehand to get a circle and then did the rest of the identifications.

Comment: Is is true that the neighborhood of the two points $1\times \{0\}$ and $1 \times \{1\}$ intersect because they both contain the point $1$ in $X$? Or am I thinking wrong..

Comment: Simpler argument for lack of Hausdorff  property would be lack of limit uniqueness.

Comment: @JBIBB Pick nbhds of $1 \times \{0\}$ and $1 \times \{1\}$ in the two copies of the intervals in $Y$. Any two such nbhds will contain pts $t \times \{0\}$ and $t \times \{1\}$ respectively such that $t  \neq 1$. Thus $q(t \times \{1\})  = q(t \times \{0\})$, so the image of the nbhds will intersect. If you try to visualize the space, it'd be clear that it's non-Hausdorff (yet $T_1$).

Comment: Okay thank you! The only thing left to understand for me is why $q(t\times \{1\})=q(t\times \{0\})$, why is this true?

Comment: @JBIBB $t \times \{1\} \sim t \times \{0\}$ ...

Comment: Ooh because you 'glue' them together? Thanks!

Comment: @JBIBB Yes. ${{{}}}$

Comment: I looked this over and I'm still trying to understand why $X$ can be obtained as a quotient of $S^1$. Can you explain it further?

Comment: @JBIBB $X$ is the space obtained from gluing each point $t$ in $[0, 2] \times 0$ to $t$ in $[0, 2] \times 1$, $t \neq 1$. First glue the endpoints $0$ and $2$ of the two intervals first. Can you see the circle? Then glue the rest of the points to see why $X$ is a quotient of $S^1$.

Comment: Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

if you shift by $-1$ and consider any sequence in $Y$ which decreases monotonically to zero. then the image of this sequence in $X$ converges to two distinct points, so $X$ cannot be Hausdorff.

call the two exceptional points $A$ and $B$. let  $N$ be an open neighbourhood of $A$ not containing $B$. then $N \cup \{B\}\setminus \{A\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $B$ not containing $A$. since the sequence does not contain either $A$ or $B$ the criteria for convergence in $X$ to $A$ and $B$ are identical to the criterion for convergence to zero in $Y$

Comment: How do you know this? Can you prove it?

Comment: i've added some further reasoning. hope it helps